# How do i model this plastic handle?

Tags: modeling

Another question from a sad rookie: 
I managed to properly model this 5 liter bottle (Thanks for the amazing guidance from a user in my previous question) and now i need a cap and a handle for the bottle. The cap is pretty easy to model but this plastic handle is a different story. I don't even know where to start — it is such a complicated object. I was thinking about modeling it with proportional editing — no luck so far... Any tips and tricks for this kind of work?[image]

Comment: I am newbie in Blender, but if I am not mistaken you may create straight handle first then bend it with curve as well using curve modifier

Comment: Great thinking man! I still have to develop this kind of understanding of modeling. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably should use curves to do this, as @R Palo has shown, because it makes it easier to go back and alter moves you made earlier; ( it's less *destructive* ). But this is the sort of way I would hack a one-off together for myself, if I knew there were going to be no changes.

[image]

X across, Y up. All the modeling is done flipping in and out of 2 levels of subdivision (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> and <kbd>2</kbd> on the keyboard)

1. Starting with a 16-sided nGon circle, <kbd>I</kbd> Inset, verts <kbd>J</kbd> joined as shown
2. <kbd>V</kbd> rip the longitude, delete the inner face and right half, assign a Mirror modifier in X with 'Merge' and 'Clip' checked.
3. (From now on working on the left half,) select the horizontal radial
   edge, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> spread a couple of
   loops on either side to the right width to extrude a handle.
   <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> Extrude the
   handle,<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> merge the inner-rim  vertices, and
   <kbd>X</kbd> > Dissolve the edge to make the kite-shape shown..
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> cut a loop across the handle, ready to
   extrude downwards.
4. Extrude downwards, and put the 3D cursor roughly at the center of the arc you intend to make at the bottom. <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> Spin the bottom edge through a negative angle to roughly form the arc. Go into the tool's settings to adjust the angle, center and number of segments. (Center Z should be 0)
5. Same as 4, spin from the downward facing edge. <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> Scale the vertices near the center line, so they weld together
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> put in a couple of edge loops as shown.

[image]

1. <kbd>E</kbd> Extrude the whole shape in Z to form the base thickness of the handle... then  select the shown region of faces to <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> the finger-grip.
2. On the other side, select all the faces of the original ring and <kbd>I</kbd> inset, so you can select a region of faces to extrude down Z to make the neck.

Now you could just put a Bevel Modifier by 'Angle' to bevel all the sharp edges, but it would probably be more accurate to go round <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> putting in *holding loops*, <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> sliding them close to soft edges to make them sharper.

Once you have some habits, and get to know how to avoid various 'gotchas', this stuff is a lot quicker to do than to describe.)

[image]

One option, when finished, is to bend the whole thing using a Lattice Deform modifier.

Comment: @IlezSnakeEyes don't tick me until you have! ( and.. psst... _whispers_ anyway, I think you should give it back to Palo... I really wouldn't mind)

Comment: Very detailed answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I would do it:

1. Create a bezier curve for the in the shape of the handle's profile. Life is easier if you put the object's origin at one end.

[image: Profile Curve]

2. Create another curve in the shape of the handle.  To simplify things, I left the origin at the World Center and used a mirror modifier. 
   [image: Handle Shape Curve]
3. With the handle shape selected, go into the Curve properties, Geometry section and create a bevel, using the profile curve as the bevel object.
   [image: Bevel Options]

That should give you the basic geometry.  You could convert to mesh, add a solidify modifier and make any tweaks you wanted from there.
[image: Basic Geometry]